# Local PHP file won't open in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, dreamweaver

When I right click my local PHP file and select "open with Firefox" Firefox gets the focus for a second, but then the file opens in Dreamweaver instead. The same happens when I drag the file onto Firefox, or enter the URL ("file:///...") manually, or expressly select Firefox as the default application for PHP files. How can I get Firefox to show the file?

Comment: @Downvoter: what's wrong with this question?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. +1 to cancel downvote

Answer (score 9):

Firefox is not capable of handling PHP files, therefore it delegates their handling to a program that can do so (in your case, this is Dreamweaver).

PHP files should be served by a web server to the client (Firefox), which will display you the rendered content (probably HTML). PHP files are rendered by the PHP interpreter and then they are served using the HTTP protocol to a client as a web resource. So actually, you never open a PHP file with a browser, you just consume the HTTP resource that corresponds to the rendered output of that file.

Comment: Which sucks, because PHP files are basically just HTML with some "fancy tags" which a standard-complaint browser should gracefully ignore :P

Comment: I actually did open .php files in Firefox years ago, but they suddenly just stopped being opened by the explorer itself.

Answer (score 3):

I have this solution to open a php on linux :

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

and open a firefox and go to the page :
http://localhost:8000/index.php
It works well for me.

Comment: That's the real solution!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox can show .html-files. You have to install a webserver (xampp) to interprete .php-files. When xampp is installed, start xampp-control-panel, open your browser and (in case ur file is "test.php" in "c:\xampp\htdocs\test.php") and type `http://localhost/test.php`.

But first, right-click any php-file->Open with...->choose program, then select Firefox in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You must install a local web server like xamp, wamp or easyphp.

Then you locate your files in that's www directory and see your file in browser with path:

```
localhost/myphp.php
```

Have a good time.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way is to rename localhost/yourfile.php onto localhost/yourfile.html. (Tested on loop's Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Now is a html file. so this doesn't fit as an answer

Answer (score -2):

You should deactivate adblock for localhost (or your domain), it should runs.
ABP icon -> click on deactivate on localhost -> F5